# org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud

When I start a microservice,throw this error:`org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V`. This is the log detail :

```
18:37:48.050 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.scripting.DefaultScriptEvaluatorFactory as ValidatorFactory-scoped script evaluator factory.
18:37:48.546 [background-preinit] WARN org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder - For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
18:37:48.966 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.AppStarter.main(AppStarter.java:51)
```

I search from Internet and says the spring boot imcompatiable with spring cloud and I should change the spring boot version to 1.5.3.RELEASE. But I am sure not this problem and I run this server fine.Why this happen to my project?This is my spring cloud version and spring boot version in my parent pom.xml:

```
  <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
  <spring-boot.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
```

And this is my full pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>soa-robot</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.sportswin.soa</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <soa-robot-api.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</soa-robot-api.version>
        <springfox-swagger.version>2.2.2</springfox-swagger.version>
        <spring-boot-main_class>com.sportswin.soa.robot.AppStarter</spring-boot-main_class>
        <soa-user-api.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</soa-user-api.version>
        <soa-red-envelope-api.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</soa-red-envelope-api.version>
        <ws-red-envelope-api.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</ws-red-envelope-api.version>
        <soa-tick-api.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</soa-tick-api.version>
    </properties>

    <artifactId>soa-robot-service</artifactId>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--添加热部署-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xuxueli</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxl-job-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 项目中用到了Feign注解，引入此包 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 用于注册中心访问账号认证 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--user define microservice-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sportswin.soa</groupId>
            <artifactId>soa-user-api</artifactId>
            <version>${soa-user-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sportswin.soa</groupId>
            <artifactId>soa-robot-api</artifactId>
            <version>${soa-robot-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sportswin.misc</groupId>
            <artifactId>soa-misc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sportswin.soa</groupId>
            <artifactId>soa-red-envelope-api</artifactId>
            <version>${soa-red-envelope-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sportswin.soa</groupId>
            <artifactId>ws-red-envelope-api</artifactId>
            <version>${ws-red-envelope-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sportswin.soa</groupId>
            <artifactId>soa-wallet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${soa-wallet-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sportswin.soa</groupId>
            <artifactId>soa-tick-api</artifactId>
            <version>${soa-tick-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!--build -->
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>resources/**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!--热部署配置-->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!--fork:如果没有该项配置,整个devtools不会起作用-->
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <charset>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</charset>
                    <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                            <charset>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</charset>
                            <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a mixed versions of spring boot jars.